# Deleting values connected to each other in the database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

My database models.py looks like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Bike(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bikes')
```

When I am deleting an entry in the table `Item` it also deletes everything that is associated in the table `Bike`. But when I am deleting an entry in the `Bike` table it doesn't delete any data in the `Item` table. Is there any possible way to delete all data in the `Item` table, when you delete an entry in the `Bike` table?

Answer (score 0):

First, the behavior you describe (`Bike` is deleted when you delete `Item`) corresponds to the CASCADE argument you put in the field:

```
item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You should know, `CASCADE` is not the only behavior available, you can check them out [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

But I don't think any of them has the exact behavior you want.
To achieve this behavior you should use a [pre_delete or post_delete signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete). But in the end this is not a good solution in my opinion.

From what I read I understand that `Bike` and `Item` are not just related. They are the same thing. You shouldn't represent their relationship with a `OneToOneField` (from what I see). `Bike`should be a child of `Item` so that a `Bike` instance has every attribute of `Item`and the attributes you want specifically for the a `Bike`. With this solution you'll find things more scalable and every use of your models will be more logical. You can learn more about [model inheritance in the Django Documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

If I were wrong, please tell me.